# Run R function in Python

Tags: python, r

I would like to ask you for a starting point or an idea to search for information on the subject. I have found many post about "how to run R script in Python",  but I just need to use a function inside a specific package. So, I would like to know if it is possible to invoke a R function, using my data in Python and get the output. Thanks in advance!

Comment: There are several packages in Python or R side to convert data (`rpy2`, `reticulate`, etc.) in session. Additionally, either one can run command lines to call the other one (`subprocess`, `system`, etc.). Even both can exchange data with compatible types like Arrow project (`parquet`, `feather`) or commonly used text format (`csv`). Please [research](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/1422451) these *many* ways, then pick one to make an earnest attempt. Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

I would look into rpy2. It takes a minute to set up but you can call R packages and use their functions fairly easily. All you have to do is use importr followed by the package you want to use from there. A few places to get started are:
https://rpy2.github.io/doc/v3.0.x/html/robjects_functions.html
https://medium.com/analytics-vidhya/calling-r-from-python-magic-of-rpy2-d8cbbf991571

Best of luck.